# how to solve error due to chunksize in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a large csv file and run a code. I use chunk size to do the same.

```
file = "./data.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep="/", header=0,iterator=True, chunksize=1000000, dtype=str)
print len(df.index)
```

I get the following error in the code:

```
AttributeError: 'TextFileReader' object has no attribute 'index'
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: There is no way the code presented above threw those errors. Please share the full code and traceback. Also, when you set the `iterator` parameter to `True`, what is returned is NOT a dataframe; it is an iterator of dataframe each the size of the integer passed to the `chunksize` parameter. Basically, you will need to loop through the `df` variable to access the multiple dataframes.

Comment: can you please explain in detail?

Comment: I'd be happy to once you've shared more code and the full traceback/error. The bottom line is: the variable `df` is NOT a dataframe. It is an [`iterator`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking) of dataframes. You can access the dataframes one by one by looping through the `iterator`.

Comment: for example, i get attribute error for using :print len(df.index)

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those errors are stemming from the fact that your `pd.read_csv` call, in this case, does not return a `DataFrame` object. Instead, it returns a [`TextFileReader`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking) object, which is an [`iterator`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator). This is, essentially, because when you set the `iterator` parameter to `True`, what is returned is NOT a `DataFrame`; it is an `iterator` of DataFrame objects, each the size of the integer passed to the `chunksize` parameter (in this case `1000000`).
Specific to your case, you can't just call `df.index` because, simply, an `iterator` object does not have an `index` attribute. This does not mean that you cannot access the `DataFrames` inside the `iterator`. What it means is that you would either have to loop through the iterator to access one `DataFrame` at a time or you would have to use some kind of way of concatenating all those `DataFrames` into one giant one.

If you are considering just working with one `DataFrame` at a time, then the following is what you would need to do to print the indexes of each `DataFrame`:

```
file = "./data.csv"
dfs = pd.read_csv(file, sep="/", header=0,iterator=True, chunksize=1000000, dtype=str)

for df in dfs:
    print(df.index)
    # do something
    df.to_csv('output_file.csv', mode='a', index=False)
```

This will save the `DataFrames` into an output file with the name `output_file.csv`. With the `mode` parameter set to `a`, the operations should append to the file. As a result, nothing should be overwritten.

However, if the goal for you is to concatenate all the DataFrames into one giant `DataFrame`, then the following would perhaps be a better path:

```
file = "./data.csv"
dfs = pd.read_csv(file, sep="/", header=0,iterator=True, chunksize=1000000, dtype=str)

giant_df = pd.concat(dfs)

print(giant_df.index)
```

Since you are already using the `iterator` parameter here, I would assume that you are concerned about memory. As such, the first strategy would be a better one. That basically means that you are taking advantage of the benefits that `iterators` offer when it comes to memory management for large datasets.

I hope this proves useful.

Comment: i have another doubt :) i am running a code inside this forloop, and since i use chunksize, only 1000 lines will be running in the beginning . and i save the output in the end. will the outfile gets overwritten every time a set of 1000 lines gets selected or the output file will have the output of the complete input ?

Comment: yes. i am saving it back to csv file using the command : df. to_csv

Comment: is there any way to solve IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds ?? :(

Comment: @Iris please edit your question with the code that is causing the error.

Comment: I'm reading tables with multiple columns of float, string, dates and so forth. Read_csv works perfectly with iterator=False but can fail on say 6th chunk with type comparison errors. If using reindex it remembers old indexes sometimes. The exact same code fails with iterator=true even though the chunk operations are mutually exclusive. Something wrong in my opinion with casting or the chunking algorithm.