# pandas csv error 'TextFileReader' object has no attribute 'to_html'

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a large csv file using Pandas and then serving it using Flask. I am getting the error `'TextFileReader' object has no attribute 'to_html'`. I think chunk size is causing the issue, but I can't open a file above 4GB without it.

```py
from flask import Flask, session, request, json,Response,stream_with_context,send_from_directory,render_template
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/readcsv')
def host_data():
    csvname=request.args.get('csvname')
    df=pd.read_csv(csvname,chunksize=5000)
    return df.to_html(header="true")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to solve error due to chunksize in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988406/how-to-solve-error-due-to-chunksize-in-pandas)

Comment: yeah kind of, another way to look at ans by diasbling index.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using `chunksize` you will get a generator of chunks. You should concatenate them for example using the following:

```
df = pd.concat((chunk for chunk in pd.read_csv(csvname,chunksize=5000)))
```

Serving a big file like this without implementing some sort of pagination, will create a total blocking response from your server, that will lead the user to wait till the file is opened and properly rendered as html.

Comment: any hint on simplest way to use Pagination, i wish to keep it simple as just need to be able to browse csv.

Comment: the simplest thing that comes to my mind it's adding 2 queries param:
chunck_size and page. Then you have an endpoint that show the first page, with 2 other link, next and previous, and each time that you clik the links, you call the endpoint itself switching between pages, in this case, you will read part of the csv file, without actually reading  all of it.