# Pandas read_csv error while using to_dict

Tags: python, pandas

Previously i was using python DictReader to read and load each row in python dict, But now due to some design changes i have to use pandas to do the same. But while trying to achieve same behaviour i am using this code

`for idx,row_r in enumerate(pd.read_csv(input_file_path,chunksize=10000, skiprows=skip_n_rows).to_dict()):`

But i am getting this error

`AttributeError: 'TextFileReader' object has no attribute 'to_dict'`

python 3.7.6
pandas 0.23.0

P.S i am using chunksize because CSV file is large.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to solve error due to chunksize in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988406/how-to-solve-error-due-to-chunksize-in-pandas)

Comment: let me try and get back to you.

Comment: @david not worked for me

Comment: @david Thanks for the link you sent, Actually got it work. i was skipping rows and header was also skipped when converted to to_dict it showed wrong results, so pass skiprows=range(1,skip_n_rows) worked and showed exact dict i was trying to fetch. Thanks